# How to inject data class

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, koin

I have a problem by data class inject.

Data class:

```
data class CoroutinesDispatcherProvider(
    val main: CoroutineDispatcher,
    val computation: CoroutineDispatcher,
    val io: CoroutineDispatcher
)
```

And viewModel need this data class:

```
class MyViewModel(private val dispatcherProvider: CoroutinesDispatcherProvider):ViewModel() {

}
```

And finally module is:

```
val appModule = module {
    single { (main: CoroutineDispatcher, computation: CoroutineDispatcher, io: CoroutineDispatcher) ->
        CoroutinesDispatcherProvider(
            main,
            computation,
            io
        )
    }
    viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
}
```

But get error:

```
Caused by: org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create definition for 'Factory [name='MyViewModel',class='com.example.myapplication.MyViewModel', binds~(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel)]' due to error :
        Can't create definition for 'Single [name='CoroutinesDispatcherProvider',class='com.example.myapplication.CoroutinesDispatcherProvider']' due to error :
        Can't get parameter value #0 from org.koin.core.parameter.ParameterList@f87fb6
```

What is wrong by appModule?!

Comment: please, try my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a lambda in your single declaration, you should resolve the dependencies using `parametersOf()`. But you first need to initialize  the provider variable, because your `viewModel` depends on it:

```
data class CoroutinesDispatcherProvider(val main: CoroutineDispatcher, val computation: CoroutineDispatcher, val io: CoroutineDispatcher)

class MyViewModel(private val dispatcherProvider: CoroutinesDispatcherProvider) : ViewModel() {
    fun helloworld() {
        println("dispatcher: $dispatcherProvider")
    }
}


val appModule = module {
    single { (main: CoroutineDispatcher, computation: CoroutineDispatcher, io: CoroutineDispatcher) ->
        CoroutinesDispatcherProvider(main, computation, io)
    }
    viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
}


class MyKoinTest : KoinTest {
    val provider: CoroutinesDispatcherProvider by inject { parametersOf(Dispatchers.Main, Dispatchers.Default, Dispatchers.IO)}
    val viewModel: MyViewModel by inject { parametersOf(provider)}

    @Before
    fun before() {
        startKoin(listOf(appModule))
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        viewModel.helloworld()
    }
}
```

I used these dependencies (`koin_version = '1.0.2'`):

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-android-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koin_version"
testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
```